# MvvmCross, how to register Service in another assembly?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, inversion-of-control, mvvmcross

I have a "Core" project in a PCL, called **MyProject.Core** which has:

```
     public interface IPhotoService
```

I then create an Android Class Library project, called **MyProject.Core.Android**, and add the references for **MvvmCross Core** from nuget. Now by doing this I know at this point that my Android Class Library has no "setup.cs".

In **MyProject.Core.Android**, I would like to have the service (which is android specific) to be as follows:

```
    public class PhotoService : IPhotoService
```

In my Android UI project, my Setup.cs contains the following:

```
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Service")
            .AsInterfaces()
            .RegisterAsLazySingleton();
    }
```

How can I have my PhotoService register if it exists in the assembly **MyProject.Core.Android** which has no Setup.cs ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control :

> And you can also, of course, use the same type of registration logic on assemblies other than Core - e.g.:
>
> ```
>    typeof(Reusable.Helpers.MyHelper).Assembly.CreatableTypes()
>        .EndingWith("Helper")
>        .AsInterfaces()
>        .RegisterAsDynamic();
> ```

Comment: Worked like a charm, had to do it in Setup.cs in the InitializeFirstChance override. Thanks Stuart, MvvmCross rocks!!